# escape shell redirection characters in awk

Tags: bash, shell, redirect, awk, escaping

Someone had the "bright" idea that you should be able to use output redirection anywhere.

This means this two are equivalent:

```
# echo expect > more friends
# cat more
expect friends
# rm more

# echo expect friends > more
# cat more
expect friends
# rm more
```

This wouldn't be so bad, if you could escape it, and indeed you can:

```
# echo "expect > more friends"
expect > more friends

# echo 'expect > more friends'
expect > more friends
```

Indeed, you could even write something like this, and it would work as expected:

```
# echo '{ print $1 > 10 }'
{ print $1 > 10 }
```

Now let's try that with awk:

```
# echo 5 | awk '{ print $1 > 10 }'
# cat 10
5
# rm 10
```

Of course. Now if someone can tell me how that makes any sense...

But let's try other variants:

```
# echo 5 | awk "{ print $1 > 10 }"
# cat 10
5
# rm 10

# echo 5 | awk '{ print $1 \> 10 }'
awk: 1: unexpected character '\'

# echo 5 | awk '{ print $1 \\> 10 }'
awk: 1: unexpected character '\'
```

Why bash? Why?

In any case, there is a workaround for this, using < instead of > does exactly what it should:

```
# echo 5 | awk '{ print 10 < $1 }'
0
```

But again, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `bash`. `awk` does not execute `bash` code, so `print ... > file` is a pure `awk` command, so different escaping rules apply.

There is no corresponding input redirection operator, so `print $1 < 10` is simply parsed as a command to print the result of the comparison `$1 < 10`.

Comment: Thanks. I finally found how to escape it: echo 5 | awk '{ print ($1 > 10) }'